# How to calculate percentage while getting data from API response

Tags: laravel, web-frontend, laravel-http-client

I'm getting response from an API in Laravel using HTTP client. And It takes some time. I just want to calculate that how much percentage of data is fetched from API. And when progressbar of 100% complete it means data is completely fetched and ready to show. So any solution for this?

Comment: are you using queue job to perform this task?

Comment: No sir. But if needed queue job for that i will use queue job

Answer (score 0):

if you are that flexible then you can do it this way ;)
You can use queue job with livewire and tailwind css to achieve this goal.

- install tailwind.
- install livewire with this command `composer require livewire/livewire`.
- run `php artisan make:livewire YourClassWire`  to create livwire class, and you can find it under /App/Http/Livewire.
- make YourClassWire somthing like this :

```html
class YourClassWire extends Component
{
  public $visibility;
  // you need this to hide progress bar if it is 100% or  0 
  public $progress  ;
  // this will be your progress.
  public $total     ;
  // this is your total job
 protected $listeners = ['reresh']; // this will called from the view
  
  public function mount()
    {
     $this->total      = \DB::table('jobs')->count(); // you must  change this if you have multiple queue with different names
     $this->visibility = $this->total > 0 ? 'visible' : 'hidden' ; // we need it to show hide porgress ;
     $this->progress   = \DB::table('jobs')->count() * 100 / $this->total; // simple equation to get progress percentage
     $this->render(); // you now call render each time the view  refresh 
    }
    
    public function refresh()
    {
    // this function will be responsible from updating the progress
     $this->visibility = $this->total > 0 ? 'visible' : 'hidden' ; // we need it to show hide porgress ;
     $this->progress   = \DB::table('jobs')->count() * 100 / $this->total; // simple equation to get progress percentage.
    }
    public function render()
     {
               return view('livewire.your-class-wire',) // note this will created with command you executed earlier `php artisan make:livewire YourClassWire` and you can find it in view/livewire
               ->with('progress', $this->progress)
               ->with('visibility',$this->visibility);
     }
  }
```

now in your livewire view  you can create your progress bar

```html
  <div wire:poll.2s="refresh">
<div class="{{$visibility}}">
    <div class="  progress_main flex   w-3/6 bg-gray-200 rounded-full h-1 mb-4 dark:bg-gray-700">
    <!-- controll the width with the progress -->
        <div  class= "progressbar border-0 relative align-middle bg-gradient-to-r from-[#d72323] via-[#dddd03] to-[#248401] dark:bg-[#dcf5ff] h-1 rounded-full"  style="width: {{ $progress }}%">
            <div  class="overflow-hidden absolute bottom-[-9px] flex  items-center  right-0  mr-[-60px] z-30 h-6 text-2xl text-[#f36d1f]">✈️
             <!-- now this text icon will move to the end based on your progress --> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I hope this guide you to what you want..success

Answer (score 0):

You could do some logic like:

```
get data from API
foreach dataset taken, do the calculation
after the calculation store/update model
get out of the foreach loop or take the next entry
```

or if you need to calculate average or something like that you can go

```
$emptyArray = [];
foreach($responses as $response) {
                $emptyArray [$response->id][] = $response->data; // data === type of integer
            }

$emptyArray_avg = [];
        foreach($emptyArray as $arrEl) {
            $emptyArray_avg[] = array_sum($arrEl)/count($arrEl);
        }
```

**Note:** If there are a lot of data in the JSON response, queues would be a good solution for it :)

[Queues](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues)